# What does this icon on my android task mean?

Tags: android, galaxy, android-8.0-oreo, samsung-touchwiz

Please I searched everywhere. What does this icon means?

[image: notification isolate]

It apears on top of my android bar.

[image: notification]

Comment: Your phone's manual will likely tell you, and you can probably find an online version if you don't have a hard copy. This is not a suitable question for stackoverflow.

Comment: That is a status bar icon. It should not be tied to your `Notification`, just as the Bluetooth icon next to it is not tied to your `Notification`.

Answer (score 0):

according to this site. Since android 2.3
https://www.mattsbits.co.uk/item-93.html

[image: icon description]

Turned data saver off

[image: Menu]

And that's gone!